# Django admin inlines with different readonly fields

Tags: django, django-admin

Say we have model inlines in Django admin.
How can we make some fields(of inline) readonly if inline object exists but editable for new instances?

For example if model has related comments, we wont let existing comments to be editable, but possible to create new (from inline admin).

Comment: Yup, my bad, deleted the wrong answer, but this should get you going: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40001830/5421745

Comment: It might won't do, but did you try the `readonly_fields = ('fieldName',)`?

Comment: @makaveli it also provides parent children instance.